# fire an event when a open a file in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I'm developing a Netbeans plugin. So what I want is do something when we open a file in Netbeans. When we open a file in Netbeans IDE, file will be opened in a tab. For example when it opens I want to print its content.

I'm currently achieving it by `PropertyChangeListener` but it triggers not only when a new file open in a tab but also when right click minimize... and lot more. So I can't use it. What event should I use for this?

This is my current code:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                JTextComponent jtc = EditorRegistry.lastFocusedComponent();
                if (jtc != null) {
                    Document d = jtc.getDocument();
                    //more codes.....
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just checking if it is a new JTextComponent.

```
JTextComponent lastJtc = null;

public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                JTextComponent jtc = EditorRegistry.lastFocusedComponent();
                if (jtc != null && jtc != lastJtc) {
                    Document d = jtc.getDocument();
                    //more codes.....
                }
                lastJtc = jtc;
}
```